# Which characters combined with ^ don't need to be escaped in sed?

Tags: regex, sed, gnu-sed

I have checked that `^*` and `^&` match lines beginning by `*` and `&`, which I didn't since they are special characters. But `^[` doesn't work. Is this "standard" behavior? Is there any rationale behind this?

`sed` version used was "GNU sed 4.4".

Comment: There are actually 7 types of character to consider when you use regexps in sed: 1) BRE regexp metachars (need to be escaped to be literal), 2) ERE regexp metachars (are literal **unless** they are escaped or used with  e.g. -E in some seds), 3) script delimiters (usually `/` but can be any), 4) backreference metachars (e.g. `\1`), 5) chars that mean different things in different contexts (e.g. `^` in `^x` vs `[^x]` vs `[x^y]`, or `-` in `a-c` vs `[a-c]` vs `[ac-]`), 6) chars with different meanings in different seds (e.g. `\<`) and 7) every other char (literal). Happy googling :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [POSIX.1-2017](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/):

> The sed utility shall support the BREs described in XBD [Basic Regular Expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03), ... **<sup>[[sed](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html#tag_20_116_13_02)]</sup>**

Reading the POSIX section on BREs, we read:

> A BRE special character has special properties in certain contexts. Outside those contexts, or when preceded by a <backslash>, such a character is a BRE that matches the special character itself. The BRE special characters and the contexts in which they have their special meaning are as follows:
>
> - **`.[\`:**
>     The <period>, <left-square-bracket>, and <backslash> shall be special except when used in a bracket expression (see [RE Bracket Expression](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05)). **An expression containing a '[' that is unescaped and is not part of a bracket expression produces undefined results.**
> - **`*`:**
>     The <asterisk> shall be special **except** when used:
>
>   - In a bracket expression
>   - **As the first character of an entire BRE (after an initial '^', if any)**
>   - **As the first character of a subexpression (after an initial '^', if any)**; see BREs [Matching Multiple Characters](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_06)
> - **`^`:**
>     The <circumflex> shall be special when used as an anchor (see [BRE Expression Anchoring](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_08)). The <circumflex> shall signify a non-matching list expression when it occurs first in a list, immediately following a <left-square-bracket> (see [RE Bracket Expression](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05)).
> - **`$`:**
>     The <dollar-sign> shall be special when used as an anchor.
>
> **<sup>source: [Basic Regular Expressions, Special characters](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_03)</sup>**

So to answer the OPs question using the above:

- `&` is not a special character, so `^&` is expected to work
- `[` should always be escaped if it is not used as a bracket expression.
- `*` is not special after an initial `^` when the latter is an anchor.

So all observed statements by the OP are therefore valid.

There is however still an interesting paragraph in [RE Bracket Expression](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05):

> A bracket expression is either a matching list expression or a non-matching list expression. It consists of one or more expressions: ordinary characters, collating elements, collating symbols, equivalence classes, character classes, or range expressions. **The <right-square-bracket> ( `]` ) shall lose its special meaning and represent itself in a bracket expression** if **it occurs first in the list (after an initial <circumflex>( `^` ), if any)**. Otherwise, it shall terminate the bracket expression, **unless it appears in a collating symbol (such as `[.].]` ) or is the ending <right-square-bracket> for a collating symbol, equivalence class, or character class**. The special characters `.`, `*`, `[`, and `\\` ( <period>, <asterisk>, <left-square-bracket>, and <backslash>, respectively) shall lose their special meaning within a bracket expression.
>
> **<sup>source: [Basic Regular Expressions, RE Bracket Expression](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05)</sup>**

This implies that `]` cannot be escaped in a bracket expression. This means:

The following work:

```
$ echo '[]' | sed 's/[^]x]/a/'
a]
$ echo '[]' | sed 's/[^x[.].]]/a/'
a]
```

but this does not work as expected:

```
$ echo '[]' | sed 's/[^x\]]/a/'
[]
```

So in a Bracket Expression, dont escape it, but collate it!

Answer (score 2):

See [`sed` "3.3 Overview of Regular Expression Syntax" documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html).

The `&` char is not a special regex char, it does not need escaping in a regex pattern. Note that `&` can be parsed as a special construct in the *replacement* pattern where is refers to the whole match.

The `*` is not special when it is at the start in GNU `sed` (`^*` is a pattern that matches a `*` at the start of the string):

> POSIX 1003.1-2001 says that `*` stands for itself when it appears at the start of a regular expression or subexpression, but many nonGNU implementations do not support this and portable scripts should instead use `\*` in these contexts.

The `[` starts a bracket expression and must have a paired `]` to close the expression, hence it is an error.